# pandas dayofyear for a period of 2 years

Tags: pandas, datetime

I am familiar with dayofyear. However, this time I have dates that span 2 years (2018, 2019). I'd like to get the day of year that would go from 1 to 730 (365+365). For example, Jan 3rd, 2019 should be 368 and Jan 3rd, 2018 should be 3. Is there a built-in way to do this? or do I need to write some function manually?

Thanks

Comment: Nope. No built in function you'll have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `year` as well being even or odd and you then have 1 to 730

```
import datetime as dt
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date":pd.date_range(dt.datetime(2018,1,1), dt.datetime(2019,12,31))})
df["Date"].dt.dayofyear * ((df["Date"].dt.year % 2) + 1)
```

Comment: that works, except that you are multiplying. The operation should be addition.